# How do I create a div whose gradients change according to cursor position?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a glassmorphism div but I want to make it more realistic.

```css
.glassCard{
    width: 60vh;
    height: calc(100% - 55%);
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 30px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.123) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.548) 100%);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 50px 0 rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.2 );
    backdrop-filter: blur( 10.0px );
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 15.0px );
    border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
        border-top-width: 1px;
        border-right-width: 0px;
        border-bottom-width: 0px;
        border-left-width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro', sans-serif;
    animation-name: floating;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="glassCard">
                        <div class="cardHead">
                                <img class="cardChip" src="/library/assets/Daco_4690777 (1) (1).png" alt="">
                                <img class="visaCard" src="/library/assets/visa (1).png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="crdNum">1234  ****  1234 ****</div>
                        <div class="cardFoot">
                            <div class="crdHolder">
                                <div class="crdHolderHead">
                                    Card Holder
                                </div>
                                <div class="crdHolderName">
                                    John Doe
                                </div>
                                <div class="crdHolderName">
                                    <span></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I want to make the background gradient change the angle according to cursor position around the card. So it give a reflective look. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOU WANT THIS?:-

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('.mouse-cursor-gradient-tracking');
btn.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  let rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  let x = e.clientX - rect.left;
  let y = e.clientY - rect.top;
  btn.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
  btn.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
});
```

```css
.mouse-cursor-gradient-tracking {
  position: relative;
  background: #7983ff;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mouse-cursor-gradient-tracking span {
  position: relative;
}

.mouse-cursor-gradient-tracking:before {
  --size: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--x);
  top: var(--y);
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, pink, transparent);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: width 0.2s ease, height 0.2s ease;
}

.mouse-cursor-gradient-tracking:hover:before {
  --size: 200px;
}
```

```html
<button class="mouse-cursor-gradient-tracking">
  <span>Hover me</span>
</button>
```